# cURL запрос в Python с загрузкой json файла

Tags: python, curl, requests

Всем доброго дня! В питоне не силён, однако стоит задача, и нужно её решить.

Есть такая курла:

```
curl -viL --basic --user <AccessKey>:<SecretKey> \ -H "Accept: application/json" -d "@request.json" \ -POST "<EndPointURL>"
```

В командной строке выполняется успешно. Однако нужно как-то выполнить её в питоне, и я не особо понимаю как именно это сделать. Немного погуглив попробовал либу requests, однако при запросе возвращается 403 ошибка.

```
    auth = (self.access_key, self.secret_key)

    headers = {'Accept': 'application/json'}

    files = {'document': open(json_file, 'rb')}

    r = requests.post(method_url, files=files, auth=auth, headers=headers)
```

Направьте пожалуйста в правильную сторону. Возможно ли вообще подобный запрос выполнить через requests? Или придется ковырять какой-ниубдь pycURL? Может у кого найдутся примеры кода?

**UPD**
Попробовал притвориться браузером - не помогло, результат тот же.

```
    auth = (self.access_key, self.secret_key)

    headers = {'Accept': 'application/json', 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (K HTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36'}

    files = {'document': open(json_file, 'rb')}

    r = requests.post(method_url, files=files, auth=auth, headers=headers)
```

Comment: [Может вид аутентификации не подходит?](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/authentication/)

Comment: Не, в апи basic auth юзается, вроде всё верно 

-- All API endpoints are authenticated using your API token over HTTP basic auth. API tokens have a unique Access Key and Secret Key that are used during API authentication.

Comment: Насколько я помню, вроде `curl` мудрит с типами клиентов. Может попробовать хедеров побольше накидать, прикинувшись браузером?

Comment: Попробовал, не помогло. Код добавил в вопрос.

Comment: Почитайте тут варианты, как посмотреть, какие хедеры посылает `curl`, ну и попробуйте их повторить в своём коде в точности: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3252851/how-to-display-request-headers-with-command-line-curl

Comment: Проблема решилась куда проще. Всем спасибо. Решение оставил ниже.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решена. Косякнул, и передавал файл через параметр files. Конкретно в моём случае в курле файл передаётся в -d:

```
-d "@request.json"
```

То есть в requests его нужно было сразу в параметр data закидывать. Итоговый рабочий код:

```
    auth = (self.access_key, self.secret_key)

    headers = {
        'Accept': 'application/json'
    }

    data = open(json_file, 'rb')

    r = requests.post(method_url, data=data, auth=auth, headers=headers)
```